# Why context menu doesn't opens in fragment?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create context menu inside fragment. My sequence of actions:

1)Create resource directory and menu file (context_menu.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/download"
    android:title="Download"/>

<item android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:title="Hello"/>

<item android:id="@+id/bye"
    android:title="Bye"/>
```

2)Setup button inside oncreateView()

```
val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.download_button)
    registerForContextMenu(button)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Button works. Toast appears.

3)Override method onCkeateContextMenu() inside my fragment

```
override fun onCreateContextMenu(
    menu: ContextMenu,
    v: View,
    menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?
) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
    requireActivity().menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu)
}
```

Pressing the button does not open the menu. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inappropriate Context Menu within a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825118/inappropriate-context-menu-within-a-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

After registering the context menu with `registerForContextMenu()`, you need to start the action mode with [`activity.startSupportActionMode(someCallback)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#startSupportActionMode(androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode.Callback))

Comment: I register the context menu inside fragment onCreateView() method and there i can't call startSupportActionMode(someCallback) becauseactivity from requireActivity() method doesn't contain such method.

Comment: @Novikov you need to cast `requireActivity()` to your Activity that hosts this fragment .. like `(requireActivity() as MainActivity).startSupportActionMode(callback)` .. change `MainActivity` to your activity name

Comment: i did what you told me, but it doesn't helps!